# Swift 3.0 TapGesture to Get Rid of Keyboard and not Interfere with Table View

Tags: swift, tableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have looked up previous questions dealing with getting rid of a keyboard and not interfering with a table view and found the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.delegate = self


    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddressVC.hideKeyboard))
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    //searchResultsTableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}
func hideKeyboard()
    {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

It seems that when I run this in the simulator, that when I tap the tableViewCell lightly, it registers as a tap to dismiss the keyboard and not as a tap to the tableView. However, if I tap and hold for a little longer in the simulator, it will both dismiss the keyboard and register as didSelectAtRow for the tableView. I was wondering if there code that can deal with this issue (or similar code that can do the same thing), or this isn't an issue at all and the simulator is less sensitive than an actual phone. (I can't set up my actual phone to test at the moment.)

Comment: Is there a line of code that says, that if the click is inside the tableView, then the tap gesture is not applied? This would solve my problem. I just don't know how to complete that conditional.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the didSelectRow getting called on tap and hold, instead of the tap gesture recogniser, is because it is getting treated as a long press gesture, and since no long press gesture recogniser is defined, the touch is transferred to the view below. So a possible solution could be you add both a tapGesture recogniser, and a long press gesture recogniser, and on both the selectors call `**self.view.endEditing(true)**`. However make sure you remove the gesture recogniser after that, to enable interactions with the tableView afterwards.

```
@IBAction func tappedOutside(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(sender)
}

@IBAction func longPressOutside(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(sender)
}
```

Comment: I can give this a try. How do I call these functions? Do I need to connect these to the storyboard at all?

Comment: No need to connect to storyboard, these functions are nothing but the selectors of the gestureRecognizers, similar to the hideKeyboard function in your code. If you are adding the gestureRecognizers through code as you have done, you can add them there itself. In my sample, I added them through storyboard, hence IBAction methods.